# How to loop through multiple images selected via gallery. in android

Tags: java, android, json, api, upload

**Can you help to fix multiple images upload using for loop in Single file API?**

The below code only uploads 2 images, the first and the last image, while the last image is looped multiple-times equaling the number of images selected.

```
//pick the gallery images 
ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
ArrayList < Uri > mArrayUri = new ArrayList < Uri > (); //list of images
for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) { //mClipData displayed picked images count

ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
Uri uri = item.getUri();
mArrayUri.add(uri); /// add the images to list

bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), mArrayUri.get(i)); //pass    the images with position
System.out.println("sizebitmap::" + bitmap);
saveImage(bitmap); //it calls the server upload method
// Get the cursor
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
cursor.close();

galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mArrayUri);
gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
.getLayoutParams();

mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);

}



//server upload code

try {
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(url);
client.connectForMultipart();
client.addFormPart("name", "ren");
    client.addFormPart("machine_element_name_id", "9");
    client.addFilePart("file", "ic_launcher_background.png", bytes.toByteArray());
    client.finishMultipart();
    String data = client.getResponse();
    System.out.println("res:" + data);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```